# How can I make fgets() read all of the 1024 byte line?

Tags: c, file-io, byte, fgets

I have a reading issue with fgets().

```
char buf[1024];
fgets(buf, 1024, inputFile);
printf("%s", buf);
```

"This is pretty much my snippet of code that is reading the text..
I have, what I believe, is a 1024 line.

> Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some
>   inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt
>   ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have
>   disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have
>   been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten
>   himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on
>   the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father
>   Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and
>   courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll
>   win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that
>   Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over
>   this affair, just as they have."He determined to drop his litigation
>   with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and
>   fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the
>   rights had becom much less valuable, and he had indeed the vaguest

When I run the code though, my result is

> Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some
>   inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt
>   ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have
>   disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have
>   been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten
>   himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on
>   the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father
>   Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and
>   courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll
>   win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that
>   Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over
>   this affair, just as they have."He determined to drop his litigation
>   with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and
>   fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the
>   rights had becom much less valuable, and he had indeed the vagues

Seems like the letter t is missing. I used Microsoft Word to count the number of bytes, and it seems like it says 1024 for my first line, and 1023 bytes for my result. My code doesn't seem incorrect. Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to allocate space for the null terminator, or 1 more character.

Comment: Ah. So fgets should be 'getting' 1025 bytes for, in actuality, 1024 bytes?

Comment: Ah sorry. I guess my search wasn't specific enough. The title of that page is a little vague. Thank you so much!